# Qt Creator Python debugger

Tags: python, debugging, qt-creator, debuggervisualizer

After using QtCreator on C++ projects for years, and seeing it being advertised for python development I tried and it works.

But, no debugger?

Even SublimeText has a python debugger https://github.com/daveleroy/SublimeDebugger.

So how do we approach the issue of having a python debugger on QtCreator? Those using QtCreator to develop in python, how you do it?